# DbUpdateException error occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So I get an DbUpdateException error every time i try to save my data.

This is my code:

```
tbl_UAM uam = new tbl_UAM
                  {
                        MDMRefNumber = tbxLastName.Text.Trim(),
                        SARId = tbxSARIdNewUAM.Text.Trim(),
                        FirstName = tbxFirstName.Text,
                        LastName = tbxLastName.Text,
                        CountryOfOrigin = cbxCountryOrigin.SelectedIndex,
                        PhoneNumber = tbxPhoneNumber.Text,
                        Center = Convert.ToInt16(cbxRRC.SelectedIndex),
                        Building = tbxBuilding.Text,
                        Floor = tbxFloor.Text,
                        SpecificDetails = tbxSpecificDetails.Text,
                  };

using (var context = new DemoDbEntities())
{
    context.tbl_UAM.Add(uam);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and this is my error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Now I know where the problem is. It's actually Identity specification problem because in my database I have turned auto-increment set to "Yes". I also know that I have to set Identity specification to false, I just don't know how to do it in my code and I cant really understand and implement it. Can someone explain to me how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the ID column in your class definition. Something like this:

```
public  class tbl_UAM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the entity identifier
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    // the rest of columns
```

}

Comment: Is it 'SARId' that gives you the error? If yes, I need to ask why you are trying to assign a value to it. Just remove the property initialization from your code.

Comment: no, its Id which i just added as u instructed. I have to remind you that I'm using Model First.

Comment: Can you post the inner exception please? I'd like to know what the exact error is